# component property passed from Application Controller contains invalid character error

Tags: ember.js

My application controller is observing the current path correctly.  I don't know if the issue is the passing of the property or the setting of the property on the controller.

Application Controller:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  currentUrl: null,
  currentPathDidChange: function() {
    return window.location.href;
    // alert(currentUrl);
  }.observes('currentPath').property('currentUrl')

});
```

Template:

```
<h2>page 1234</h2>
{{social-footer-login pageUrl=controllers.application.currentUrl}}
```

Component:

```
<h2>social footer component</h2>

<div id="footer-container">
  <div class="facebook">
    <span id="facebook-text">f</span>
  </div>
  <div class="linkedin">
    <span id="linkedin-text">in</span>q
  </div>
  <div class="fb">
    <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="button" data-size="small" data-mobile-iframe="false"><a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" + pageUrl>Share</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Error:
String contains an invalid character
setAttribute@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:16331:21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `pageUrl` variable needs to be used in a Handlebars compliant manner. Instead of doing a Javascript append, reference it directly using `{{pageUrl}}` right in your template:

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="button" data-size="small" data-mobile-iframe="false"><a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={{pageUrl}}">Share</a></div>
```

That should then work.

Comment: thanks for your input, your recommdation results in this error `The operation is insecure.
getItem@eval:4269:27
get@eval:3736:18
ComputedPropertyPrototype.get@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:36389:15
get@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:35697:14
exports.default<.get@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:49720:15
setInstrumentWithStack@eval:3751:47
init@eval:3676:7
superWrapper@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:55969:17
Class@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:51167:9
_ClassMixinProps.create@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:51337:12
startModule@eval:2`

Comment: Your solution works when the component injects a service which returns the current window url, I am puzzled why but a rough working example is here in this git repo `https://github.com/ramblingbarney/literate-octo-lamp.git` should anyone be able to explain or be looking for an ember 2 example